# In my Blazor server side app I want to execute a method in the razor.cs file as soon as the related razor page is loaded. But not working

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

In my Blazor server side app I want to execute a method in the razor.cs file as soon as the related razor page is loaded. The method is reading a text file line by line and adding each line to a list. In the razor page the list elements (text lines) are shown in a table's row. But when the page is loaded my "Loading" circle is turning and turning but the method is not executed. What could be the problem?

(When I trigger the same method via a button, then everything is working fine)

My razor page

```
@if (TagService.Loading_Error_Log == true)
{
    <div class="spinner"></div>
}

<table class="log_file_table">

    @if(TagService.Error_log_loaded == true)
    {
    @for (int f = 0; f < TagService.Error_log.Count; f++)
    {
        <tr style="max-height:20px !important">
            <td class=".log_file"><pre class="preformatted">@TagService.Error_log[f]</pre></td>
            </tr>
        }

        TagService.Error_log_loaded = false;
    }
   
</table>
```

My razor.cs file

```
public partial class Logs
{

    protected override async void OnInitialized()

    {
        await Read_Error_Log();
    }

    
    public async Task Read_Error_Log()
    {
        TagService.Error_log_loaded = false;
        TagService.Loading_Error_Log = true;
        await Task.Delay(1);

        try
        {
            TagService.Error_log.Clear();
                Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
                var lines = File.ReadLines(CommonClass.error_path, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1254"));
                var line_trimmed = "";

                foreach (var line in lines)
                {
                    TagService.Error_log.Add(line);
                }
            TagService.Error_log_loaded  = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(CommonClass.error_path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Read_Error_Log() Error " + e + " " + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now));
            }
        }

        TagService.Loading_Error_Log = false;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong signature here:

`protected override async void OnInitialized()`

Should be

`protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()`

Comment: No unfortunately Task is not accepted from the compiler

Comment: Oh my mistake I didn't notice you are not using the correct method - answer edited

Comment: Additionaly: I f a trigger the method over a button then the same method is executed quite normal